# Ruby on Rails: Validating and changing a phone number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a simple phone form `<%= f.text_field :phone %>` right now. `:phone` is an integer type, so this requires that whatever the user enters into the form must be something like `5551234` instead of the more standard way of `555-1234` How can I allow the user to enter in a USA phone number like their accustomed to? I understand that I can use `validates_format_of` to validate it, but once I validate it, how can I format the number and insert the phone number into the DB as an integer?

Answer (score 17):

ActiveRecord automatically typecasts input based on the databases column type. When Ruby casts a string to an integer it drops everything after the first non-numeric character, `123-456-7890` will become `123`. This is done before the field is available in the model so the solutions given so far will not work. You need to overwrite the default write accessor!

The [ActiveRecord::Base docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) mentions two ways to overwrite the default write accessor `(field_name)=` in the model so you can process the input removing the non-digits before it needs to be typecast. There are at least three variations:

(1) Overwrite the accessor and use write_attribute to store the result in the database:

```
def phone=(value)
  value.gsub!(/\D/, '') if value.is_a?(String)
  write_attribute(:phone, value.to_i)
end
```

(2) Or use the hash notation:

```
def phone=(num)
  num.gsub!(/\D/, '') if num.is_a?(String)
  self[:phone] = num.to_i
end
```

(3) Or (in the latest versions of ActiveRecord) just call super as if it were a normal (non-dynamic) method (not shown in docs but works):

```
def phone=(num)
  num.gsub!(/\D/, '') if num.is_a?(String)
  super(num)
end
```

This is useful in a number of situations such as numbers with commas and works great with forms that supply a formatted version of the previous field value such as in an edit form or after an error in a new/create form:

```
<%= f.text_field :phone, number_to_phone(@model_data.phone) %>
```

This way you can show the user formatted data (i.e. as String) but still store an integer in the database.

One last tip on MySQL: You need to use a `BigInt` to store a phone number otherwise you will see a lot of `(214) 748-3647` phone numbers in your database as `2,147,483,647` is the max value of a normal MySQL integer - `int(11)` - obtained form `:integer` in a migration. A `BigInt` in MySQL is obtained by setting `:limit` to `8` as in this migration line:

```
change_column :model_name, :phone, :integer, :limit => 8
```

This will give you a `bigint(20)` in your table which can handle numbers up to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` which should be sufficient for any phone number.

Comment: Great answer, @Niels.  The only thing is that .gsub! returns nil if no changes are made.  .gsub works better with rails validation.  See [rails string length validation not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812019/rails-string-length-validation-not-working).  Thanks a mill, though.  Your answer got me started.

Comment: +1 for the Int/BigInt point. I never thought about that, though (for better or worse), I typically store my phone numbers as strings.

Answer (score 12):

```
phone.gsub(/\D/, '')
```

should do the trick. It removes non-digit chars.

Comment: I put `before_validation do; phone = phone.to_s.gsub(/\D/, '').to_i; end` In my model.rb file, but it's still not changing anything.

Comment: The regular expression works for me in irb, Ruby 1.8.7: `"(213) 456-7890".gsub(/\D/,'')
=> "2134567890"`

Comment: There are a number of methods to get the integer formatted for display as a phone number. See NumberHelper (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html) or the 'phone' gem (https://github.com/carr/phone)

Comment: As mentioned below by Josh, you need to say:
```ruby
self.phone = phone.gsub(...)
```
You need the 'self' when you're updating an active record field; otherwise ruby assumes you're just setting a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
"1-2-3-4".gsub('-','').to_i
# => 1234
```

You can also use Regular Expressions if you want to get more fancy, but you should be able to get away with just this.

You probably want to validate what you're storing it in the DB as, since Rails checks validations before saving. However, you can do a `before_validation` that modifies the number first. Something like this:

```
before_validation do
  phone = phone.to_s.gsub('-','').to_i
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#M001378

Comment: The only problem is that some people like to type phone numbers like `(123)555-1234` or `123-555-1234` or `(123) 555-1234`, etc. So this method doesn't quite get everything.

Comment: In that case you could use RegEx, which are more powerful. Mark's example in his answer works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got this figured out yet, but I ran into the same problem as Reti did with Mark's code.

It seems that specific `self.phone = self.phone.gsub(/\D/, '')` did the trick.

Maybe it's because at that point `phone` isn't initialized yet? I'm not sure, still a newbie here...