# rails string length validation not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I must be missing something basic but I keep getting validation errors:

app/model/person.rb

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :cell

  before_validation :format_cell_string

  validates :cell, :length => { :is => 10 }

  protected

    def format_cell_string
      self.cell = self.cell.gsub!(/\D/, '') if self.cell != nil
    end

end
```

In rails c

```
> bib = Person.new(cell: "1234567890")
> bib.save
```

leads to a ROLLBACK

> bib.errors
>   `=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fcb3cf978d8 @base=#<Person id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, cell: nil>, @messages={:cell=>["is the wrong length (should be 10 characters)"]}>`

Thinking that is could be a rails console or irb error, I also tried in my form to no avail.  Trying `bib = Person.new`, bib.save and then bib.update_attributes(cell: "0123456789") also doesn't work in the console.  Am I missing something!  I've check the [rails docs on validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#length) and the [rails api on model validations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validate) and tried many different things.  Any thoughts?  I was using rails 3.2.6 and just upgraded to rails 3.2.7.  No change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gsub!` modifies the string in place and returns `nil` [if no changes were made](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub-21):

```
"1234567890".gsub!(/\D/, '') #=> nil
```

So in the case where the field contains only digits your code is setting the field to nil before the validation which causes it to fail. Using `gsub!` on attributes is best avoided generally, as it doesn't play well with Rails' change tracking.

```
self.cell = self.cell.gsub(/\D/, '') if self.cell != nil
```

should do the trick

Comment: That's it!  Much positive karma sent your way.  Thank you!